# Cardinalidade em diagrama de classes

Tags: mysql, modelagem, cardinalidade

Quando faço diagrama de classes ou MER, a cardinalidade deve ser definida.

Como exemplo: um médico consulta de 0 a n pacientes; um paciente é consultado por 0 ou 1 médico. Por que o 0?

Comment: Um médico pode não ter consultado nenhum paciente ainda. Já o paciente é estranho, pois se ele é paciente, automaticamente se assume que ele tenha se consultado pelo menos uma vez, nesse caso seria 1:n médicos.

Comment: Imagino que o fato do paciente possuir um cadastro não implica no fato de ele possuir um médico.

Comment: O zero significa que daquele lado pode haver nenhum registro. O motivo você tem que perguntar para quem definiu que é assim.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 3):

Sempre é muito difícil falar sobre casos genéricos e abstratos assim. O caso concreto pode ser diferente.

Até onde entendi não há uma necessidade do médico ter pacientes. Então pode ser de 0 a N. Claro que você pode estabelecer uma regra de negócio que seja obrigatório que ele tenha algum paciente relacionado. E já que está estabelecendo um mínimo de 1, quem sabe pode definir um mínimo maior que 1. Pra mim esta regra não faz muito sentido, mas é como eu disse. Cada negócio com sua regra.

Nem o paciente precisa estar vinculado a um médico. Neste caso tem uma chance maior de existir a obrigatoriedade de ter um médico em determinadas situações. Eu também não faria esta exigência, não vejo motivo para tê-la, mas se quem está pedindo isto dizer que precisa justificadamente de alguma restrição extra, não tem porque não fazer.

O que eu até pensaria é se o paciente não pode estar vinculado até N médicos. Porque há exclusividade? Pode ter, mas acho pouco provável em um hospital ou clínica. Mesmo que a clínica só tenha um médico, isto é uma circunstância.

É claro que se o sistema está controlando a alocação do médico estas regras podem ser diferentes. Mas não sei se seriam. Nada impede do médico estar atendendo vários pacientes simultaneamente assim como um paciente pode estar recebendo atenção de vários médicos, talvez formando uma junta.